# React Router. Programmatic redirect to route with multiple parameters not working

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom, query-string

I'm trying to redirect the user back to a previous route via url with two dynamic parameters. However, adding those two parameters causes the redirect to be a no-op.

When I redirect without them it works fine. Also accessing the route via url works fine. It really appears to be the programmatic redirect. I've tried pushing to history stack and using the Link div- to no avail. Could anyone push me into the right direction?

url: onboarding/5f4a3ee7e28892ae792a0107/5f4a3ee7e28892ae792a0105

```
    goTo(redirectTo) {
        this.setState({ redirectTo });
    }

    renderRedirect() {
        const { redirectTo } = this.state
        const path = `/${redirectTo}`;

        if (!redirectTo) {
            return;
        }
 
        return <Redirect to={path}/>
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
         {this.renderRedirect()}
                <div
                    className={`App ${
                        window.location.pathname !== '/admin' ? 'view' : ''
                    }`}
                >
                    <SchedulePanel />
                    <img className="voxpop-logo" src={VoxPopLogo} alt="logo" />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            path="/onboarding/:eventId/:groupId"
                            exact
                            component={OnboardingView}
                        />
                        <Route path="/profile" exact component={ProfileView} />
                        <Route
                            path="/questions"
                            exact
                            component={QuestionsView}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/searching"
                            exact
                            component={SearchingView}
                        />
                        <Route path="/match" exact component={MatchView} />
                        <Route path="/chat" exact component={ChatView} />
                        <Route
                            path="/offboarding"
                            exact
                            component={OffboardingView}
                        />
                        <Route path="/admin" exact component={AdminView} />
                        <Route path="/no-match" exact component={NoMatch} />
                        <Route path="/dev" exact component={Dev}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your `<Route />` for the `/onboarding/:eventId/:groupId` route, you have the `exact` prop. This might be the issue because, as per the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool), the `exact` prop on a `<Route />` means that the URL must match *exactly*. And this, of course, won't be the case for a dynamic path.

Try it without the `exact` prop and see if it fixes it!

Comment: Thanks, that is not the issue unfortunately. Those routes have query pramaters